# Error with parameters adding to the request in Alamofire

Tags: ios, networking, parameters, swift, alamofire

I'm using the new network library called [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to do a POST request in Swift.

Alamofire allows you to build up the parameters format separately and add it. Here is my request format.

```
{
  "DeviceCredentials": {
    "UniqueId": "sample string 1"
  },
  "Personalnumber": "sample string 1"
}
```

And below is what I came up with.

```
let parameters = [
    "DeviceCredentials": ["UniqueId": uniqueID],
    "Personalnumber": personalNumber
]
```

Both `uniqueID` and `personalNumber` are of **String** type. I get no error at this point but when I try to add it to the request,

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://www.example.com/api/", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON(options: nil)).responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) -> Void in
    println(JSON!)
}
```

I get this error at the `parameters` parameter, **'String' is not identical to 'NSObject'**.

Is there something wrong with my format or is this a bug?

Thanks

**Edit**: I found that replacing `uniqueID` with an integer like so (`["UniqueId", 1]`) gets rid of the error. But I tried another format as a test which I have listed below and it compiles without any errors!

```
let paras = [
    "DeviceCredentials": ["UniqueId": uniqueID],
    "UserCredentials": ["Personalnumber": personalNumber]
]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your first example of "parameters" you have mixed types in the dictionary and Swift apparently fails to figure out the inferred type for it. You can fix this with a type annotation:

```swift
let parameters : [ String : AnyObject] = [
    "DeviceCredentials": ["UniqueId": uniqueID],
    "Personalnumber": personalNumber
]
```

In your second dictionary, "paras", all types are equal and type inference succeeds.

Comment: It's not working for me for below json , any help would be great                   let body: Parameters = [
            "test_id": 1,
            "student_id": 1,
            "delayed_mins": 10
        ]